# Angular NG5002 error Invalid ICU message and Unexpected character EOF

Tags: angular

I'm using the latest release of [Angular 17.0.0-next.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/releases/tag/17.0.0-next.6) which add support for the new control flow, I saw people in twitter talking it's working fine for them, so it must be my problem

I'm using everything as expected in a new project and replace the app.component.html with this code

```
@if(title) {
  title
} @else {
  no title
}
```

but it gives me  the following errors

```
X [ERROR] NG5002: Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:6:0:
      6 │ 
        ╵ ^

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:9:15:
      9 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


X [ERROR] NG5002: Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.) [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/app.component.html:6:0:
      6 │ 
        ╵ ^

  Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

    src/app/app.component.ts:9:15:
      9 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
        ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

link for [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gphxn6?file=src%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Those new features are in a pre-release version of angular 17. If you are using the current stable build of version 16 or older it will not work.

Comment: I'm using 17.0.0-next.6, I already wrote it, but will make it clearer

Comment: You can't use the new syntax on the stackblitz starter. You'll have to go with a webcontainer. You can fork mine : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable these block types in the angularCompilersOptions in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
 "angularCompilersOptions": {
  ....
  "_enabledBlockTypes": ["if","for","switch","defer"]
 }
}
```

Comment: this didn't resolve it immediately but after reading another answer saying they had to update Angular Langauge Service, I checked it and mine was on the latest version. What finally worked was just to restart the Angular Language Services. To do that: click ctrl + P then type ">Angular: Restart Angular Language Server", after clicking it the error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

For me just adding

```
{
 "angularCompilersOptions": {
  ....
  "_enabledBlockTypes": ["if","for","switch","defer"]
 }
}
```

to tsconfig.json did not remove the error, but updating the Angular Language Service extension in VS Code fixed the error.

Comment: Same here for me, thanks!